# VSCode, написание Debug adapter с нуля

Tags: visual-studio-code, отладка

Добрейшего времени суток. Волею судеб достался заброшенный проект для разработки адаптера отладки для широкоизвестного в узких кругах языка Atlantis Vip.
В данный момент проект умеет в подсветку синтаксиса и в компляцию проекта (вызов консольного компилятора с параметрами в задаче).
Теперь стоит вопрос в отладке, так как эта штука (Atlantis Vip) напсана на Delphi и, для отладки, используется библиотека RTL которая работает  с Share Memory был написан адаптер на дельфях, который с одной стороны поднимает http для общения с VSCode а с другой вызывает методы из RTL.
Вопрос в том, что я не могу теперь понять как правильно оформить запуск этого адаптера из VSCode
Пробовал так (launch.json)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Vip Debugger",
            "type": "vip",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "MyFile.vip",
            "runtimeExecutable": "MyDebbugerPath\VipDebuggerTest.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

пробовал так

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Vip Debugger",
            "type": "vip",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "MyDebbugerPath\VipDebuggerTest.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

судя по отсутвию логов с VipDebuggerTest.exe оно даже не пытается его запустить.
Если кто сталкивался - подскажите как правильно делать?